# how to understand 1:n relation about viewmodel:activity?

Tags: android

I'm studying mvvm. Studying this, I got one question. I heard that viewmodel can have many activities. the point is that one viewmodel used by activities share their datas. because I'm using koin for DI. one viewmodel can share their datas?

```
private val mainViewModel : MainViewModel by viewModel() 

onCreate(){
    init()
    .....
}

init(){
        mainViewModel.searchItems.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.let {item->
                if(item.body !=null) {
                    Handler().postDelayed({         
                        page++
                        adapterAddItem(item.body)
                        setVisiblity(viewDataBinding.progressBar, View.GONE)
                    }, 300)
                }else{

                   showMessage(this,"No message")
                   setVisiblity(viewDataBinding.progressBar, View.GONE)
                }
            }


        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a viewModel doesn't have activities, a viewModel shouldn't know anything about an activity. Activities have viewModels.

For sharing data, I would use Koin's singles. Those you can inject into your viewModel or activity.